Using a capacitor to mitigate voltage drop
Similar questions have been asked, but I'm having trouble finding a good answer. I spent all summer building an ice fishing house with a diesel heater that runs on 12VDC. In order to run the heater from generator power (if/when the deep-cycle battery dies) I added a 12V power supply, which worked great when I tested in the summer...but now it's cold. When I turn on the heater it gets a few seconds into its start-up cycle and trips the power supply. I'd like to add a capacitor (+ resistor?) to act as an accumulator would in a hydraulic system and prevent the power supply from tripping -- I think I know how to size the capacitor, but I'm not quite sure what the circuit should look like.
Details: 12VDC heater with a stated 8A max draw at start-up, I've been unable to measure amp draw as the power supply trips too quickly. After start-up the heater draws ~0.5A. It's come close to the min operating temps of the power supply and heater, but not colder yet. 12VDC, 120W power supply. I do have a second identical power supply that I considered adding in parallel, but the one I have is already over-sized (except for start-up) so I'd like to make that work and keep the second as a spare. Any help is greatly appreciated!

For how long must the capacitor power the heater, worst case?

"I think I know how to size the capacitor" -- Do that first, and you will see how practical that idea is.

you need a better battery with low ESR. Caps are 10k smaller energy density , NG

@PhilFreedenberg the intent isn't so much forcing the capacitor to power the heater, the power supply should have enough power. What I'm looking to do is mitigate/smooth the voltage drop / large draw to enable the power supply to continue doing its job. I've heard of a similar solution for car stereos with large subwoofers, but again I cannot find any useful solutions.

I suspect the trips are caused by the heater resistance being too low when it is cold.  If that is the case, then try a "soft-start" circuit connected in series with heater that limits the current until the heater earms up sufficiently.  This can be as simple as a resistor in parallel with the contacts of a relay.  Relay contacts are normally open, & close when relay coil is energised.
On start up, the relay contacts are open, & the resistor limits the current to prevent tripping the 12V PSU.  During this time, the heater warms up & as it does so its resistance increases.  After it reaches a certain temperature its resistance will be high enough that it no longer trips the PSU.  This is when the relay coil can be energised to close the contacts to bypass the resistor & provide full voltage to the heater.
The relay coil can be energised automatically via a timer or a temperature sensor.  Or it can be manually operated by say, a push-button or switch.
Choose resistor to catefully, its resistance has to be high enough to limit the current but not so high that it causes the heater temperature to rise too slowly.  It must also be able to handle the power, so it may need to be mounted on a heatsink.
A second heater may make an ideal "resistor", in which case rather than bypassing the "resistor" the relay contacts may reconfigure the two heaters to be in parralel across the 12V PSU, rather than in series as they would be at start up.

An NTC thermistor could work as an inrush limiter too.  The hot resistance and dissipation in the NTC would just add to the heat in the house, so it's a productive loss.

Thank you Fabio B and John D! Those two points give me enough to continue researching/testing, very helpful.

Based on your load voltage of 12V &  current of 0.5A, this NTC resistor might be ok, but please do check all details:  https://au.rs-online.com/web/p/thermistor-ics/1711819

If you found my answer helpful then please consider up voting it.  Thanks
